# Nginx slow when page does not exist

Tags: nginx

I saw in the nginx access log that most "normal" requests are processed in about 5ms.
But there are also "abnormal" requests for non-existent pages such as

"POST /vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/Util/PHP/eval-stdin.php" or
"POST /Autodiscover/Autodiscover.xml"

These are processed in about 500ms.
It's not really a problem, on repeat they are blocked by fail2ban.
But why does nginx need 100x more time when there is a request for a page that does not exist? I would rather expect less time to be needed.

Comment: What do you have under `try_files`? if you have multiple statements, it needs to go through them to check if a file could be interpreted that way.

Answer (score -1):

I have only

```
location /.well-known/acme-challenge/ {
    alias /aa/zzdom/public_html/.well-known/acme-challenge/;
}

location ~ \.php$ {
   fastcgi_pass  unix:/var/run/php/php8.0-fpm.sock;
   include snippets/inc-php.conf;
}

location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
}
```